# awk getcolumn var instead of getline var

Tags: awk, getline

awk has the 'getline var' function that I use quite often to extract the rows of a file in which a specific column (2nd in the example below) matches to the lines of another file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while(getline each_line < "patterns_file.txt") my_patterns[each_line]} $2 in my_patterns' file_to_search.txt
```

instead how can I get only a specified column from the patterns_file.txt into the array my_patterns if it has more than one column and I need only a specific column for matching (let's say 4th), something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while(getcolumn each_4th_column < "patterns_file.txt") my_patterns[each_4th_column]} $2 in my_patterns' file_to_search.txt
```

Comment: `getline` is *sometimes* the solution, not always ([see an interesting article on this by Ed Morton](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)). So you'd better post some input, output and clear explanation on what is your ultimate goal, since it might be done in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is an anti-pattern in awk. The recommended way of doing what you want is like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {my_patterns[$4];next} $2 in my_patterns' patterns_file.txt file_to_search.txt
```

There's no need to manually use `getline` in this case. Instead, the first block runs for the first file and sets keys in the array. `FNR==NR` is the idiomatic way of determining that the first file is being processed (because `FNR` is the record number in the current file and `NR` is the total record number). Using `next` means that the part outside the block is skipped for the first file.

Comment: @Omer glad to hear it. Of course, you can change the `$4` to `$0` instead of using `getline var` as well.